# Thread is not working properly

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I have a `class Machine` with some member function. In the `makeProduct` I make a thread that calls `t_make` and then `return`s. While the thread is doing it's work in the member function I still want to use `Machine`(status check, resource left, etc.)

I started like this

```
//machine.h 
private
  int stat; 
  std::thread t;
  std::mutex m;
  bool working;

//machine.cpp
    int Machine::makeProduct(){

      if(working == true) return -1;

      t = std::thread(&Machine::t_make, this);

      return 0;

    }

    void Machine::t_make(){
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m);

        //do some time-consuming work, change "stat" in progress

    }

    void Machine::Status(int &copStat){
        copStat = stat;
    }

    Machine::~Machine(){  if(t.joinable()) t.join; }

//main.cpp 
...
Machine m;

m.makeProduct();

int getStat = 0;
m.Status(getStat);

if(getStat == 1) cout<< "Product in making";
```

...

The problem is that when I call `makeProduct()` and right after that `Status()` the `copStat` doesn't  change, indicate that any work was done.

Am I using the `t` or `t_make` wrong? I tried posting `lock_guard` in every method but the threads don't intertwine. Or maybe the `t.join()` at the wrong time, but let me just mention that if I place 't.join' right after using `t = std::thread(&Machine::t_make, this);` and everything work out fine.

Comment: Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? Because right now it's hard to understand how your code snipped work together. Especially important is to know how your `Machine` class is used. And the code you show will not work as you expect (you're not *calling* the `join` function).

Comment: It's too big of a file :/ i'll try to add some more. About the `join` function, i call it in destructor.

Comment: @TheGuyWithStreetCred You left out "()". On `joinable`, too.

Comment: It looks like you have a race condition on the `stat` (and possibly the `working`) variable. Try and `std::atomic`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call Status() right after you call getProduct(), there's a good chance that the new thread hasn't started doing anything yet.  You are still in the original thread, and the new thread has to set up and start running.

Your join in the destructor is not really meaningful for this exercise.  If you wanted to make sure to collect the result and do something with it as Machine goes out of scope it may make sense, but it isn't meaningful to your question about checking Status.  If you want Status() to only return you the value after t_make() is finished, then moving your join() code to Status would work.

Look at the Futures in the standing threading library http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread#Futures.  These are utilities for executing asynchronous tasks and getting the result when the task is complete.

Comment: If i insert `sleep(1)` after I define `t` it works fine. Does that give you any clue

Comment: That's exactly what we're saying.  You're calling Status() before the task is done.  Adding a sleep(1) allows the task to complete.  If you expect Status() to give you the final answer (as opposed to some intermediate value during the assignment) then you need synchronization in the Status() function.

Answer (score 1):

If t_make is modifying 'stat', then your Status function should acquire the lock before using 'stat' in the assignment of the copStat. The memory access is currently unsafe.

As the code stand right now, if you're expecting the t_make call to be complete before calling Status, there is nothing forcing this to happen. As is, two separate threads will be autonomously completing these actions - 1 thread calling t_make and 1 thread calling Status. There is no guarantee as to what order this happens in. (this changes if you add a lock to Status)

Also, could you update your example to show how you're determing that copStat is never populated?